# Okular - Darkmode without invert images colors

Tags: okular, dark-mode

I'm studying **a lot** on screen because of the Covid19 pandemic. And it tears my eyes apart.

```
brieucdug@msi:~$ lsb_release -d && uname -r
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
5.4.0-37-generic
```

(gnome-shell)

---

## Resume

I've set the dark mode on, but it inverts image as well on a greyscale. I do not want that.
I've set my Okular setting like that (Background : Dark Grey / Font : White)

[image: okular-setting]

[image: sample]

## What I'm looking for

Right now, I've set a shortcut to toggle colors.

However, what I'd love, your guess, is that :

[image: result-want]

---

## What I found

I found these two files

```
/usr/share/config.kcfg/okular.kcfg
/usr/share/config.kcfg/okular_core.kcfg
```

With, respectively,

```
brieucdug@msi:~$ cat /usr/share/config.kcfg/okular.kcfg
...
<group name="Dlg Accessibility" >
  <entry key="HighlightImages" type="Bool" >
   <default>false</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="HighlightLinks" type="Bool" >
   <default>false</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="RecolorForeground" type="Color" >
   <default code="true" >0x600000</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="RecolorBackground" type="Color" >
   <default code="true" >0xF0F0F0</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="BWThreshold" type="UInt" >
   <default>127</default>
   <min>2</min>
   <max>253</max>
  </entry>
  <entry key="BWContrast" type="UInt" >
   <default>2</default>
   <min>2</min>
   <max>6</max>
  </entry>
 </group>
...
```

```
brieucdug@msi:~$ cat /usr/share/config.kcfg/okular_core.kcfg
...
<group name="Document">
  <entry key="PaperColor" type="Color" >
   <default code="true" >Qt::white</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="ChangeColors" type="Bool" >
   <default>false</default>
  </entry>
  <entry key="RenderMode" type="Enum" >
   <default>Inverted</default>
   <choices>
    <choice name="Inverted" />
    <choice name="Paper" />
    <choice name="Recolor" />
    <choice name="BlackWhite" />
   </choices>
  </entry>
 </group>
...
```

In the first file `okular.kcfg`, there is no mention about the pictures.

In the second one `okular_core.kcfg`, however, I thought I touch something with `<choice name="Inverted" />`, but nothing (I didn't tried to reboot, tho).

---

So, if anyone know how I could fin a workaround to get it to work as I want, I'm all ears ! :-)

Thank you, Brieuc.

PS : Sorry for these teeth pictures, hope you won't have any nightmare.
Edit :

Comment: There is also way to create simple switch, to change colors, when you need.
You can add button into the tools panel with function "toggle color change". Which will use your specified settings. (I did it just now)
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/6bttn1/shortcut_on_okular_toolbar_for_change_colors_or/dhpipca/
I was originaly looking for the solution to highlighting, which behaviors weirdly when colors are inverted, so if somebody have another tip, it would be welcome with me. :)

Comment: Well. That's how I have done. But not having to toggle would be better

Comment: Is the 'change paper color' option in the 'color mode' drop-down menu supposed to what it implies? I tried black for a white PDF, no discernible difference.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look on it, or how we would say in Czechia "We'll look at the tooth of it" :)

Best what you can accomplish by Okular is this
[image]
(The black zone doesn't include text, i didnt put it there, but its inverted)

You can do this by

**Accessibility > Change Colors > Color Mode > Invert the brightness** (its translated)

So you were close. :)

Comment: It's great ! While a little bit too contrasted, and I can't see what I'd be looking for (gingival odeamatia).. I'll look into that, thank you