# How can I invert the color of all images present in a PDF at once with Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, images, adobe-acrobat

How can I invert the color of all images present in a PDF at once with Adobe Acrobat?

E.g. in the following I'd like to invert the colors of figures 2, 3 and 4 at once (as well as all other images in the same PDF).

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has your research told you?

Answer (score 1):

According to [acrobat.uservoice.com](https://acrobat.uservoice.com/forums/590923-acrobat-for-windows-and-mac/suggestions/39397822-invert-colours-on-images-embedded-in-pdf-files), currently Acrobat doesn't have this feature.

PDF readers with this feature:

- [Okular PDF reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okular): [Okular - Darkmode without invert images colors](https://superuser.com/q/1563014/116475)
- [sioyek](https://sioyek.info/):

  [image]